# How to create tweet using tweepy API V 2

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

```
import tweepy

ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'


api = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                    access_token=ACCESS_KEY,
                    access_token_secret=ACCESS_SECRET,
                    consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
                    consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)

api.create_tweet(text='I want to Post 3 Photos and description')
```

**I'm using tweepy V2 But I don't know how to upload photos + descriptions**

Does anyone help me? **I want to tweet images with text, I've 3 image's**

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the existing answer - the reason it is not working is because you are required to use the v1 endpoint for uploading media; not the v2. Using tweepy.Client uses the v2 endpoint only.

You can get around this by using two clients, one for the upload, one for the tweet creation:

```py
import tweepy

ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxx'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'xxxx'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxx'




api = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='xxxx',
access_token=ACCESS_KEY,
access_token_secret=ACCESS_SECRET,
consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)


auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
    CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET
)
oldapi = tweepy.API(auth)
media1 = oldapi.media_upload("img1.jpg")
media2 = oldapi.media_upload("img2.jpg")
media3 = oldapi.media_upload("img3.jpg")

api.create_tweet(text='I want to Post 3 Photos and description',media_ids=[media1.media_id, media2.media_id, media3.media_id])
```

Also note that the id is called `media_id` on the output of `media_upload` - this is not super clear in the api docs which state it is called `id`:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/entities#media

You will probably need this workaround if you get issues related to the
`453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only` error.

Comment: This doesn't work for free plan, it says still 403, any workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

Had to do a little digging, as I don't have experience with tweepy, but I think I found an answer.

When you send the tweet, you can attach media using a "media id". Somewhat like this:

```
api.create_tweet(text = 'Images can be fun too!', media = {media_ids = ["1455952740635586573", "1234567890"]})
```

The media_ids list can contain multiple media IDs. However, you need to upload the images to Twitter to get the media IDs.

Tweepy provides a file upload function, that can be used like so:

```
mediaID = api.media_upload(filename)
```

Simply upload your files, put them into a dictionary, and send your tweet!

I made a little example that you can add to the end of your program.

```
import tweepy

ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'


api = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                    access_token=ACCESS_KEY,
                    access_token_secret=ACCESS_SECRET,
                    consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
                    consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)

mediaID1 = mediaID = api.media_upload("media1.png")
mediaID2 = mediaID = api.media_upload("image2.png")
mediaID3 = mediaID = api.media_upload("image3.png")

api.create_tweet(text='I want to Post 3 Photos and description',
                 media={media_ids=[mediaID1,mediaID2,mediaID3]})
```

Please refer to the Twitter documentation if you need a more accurate depiction of the Twitter API:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/manage-tweets/api-reference/post-tweets
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload

I'm still a little rusty at Python and this is my first time using Stackoverflow but this *should* work.

Comment: tweepy.errors.BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
$.media_ids: there must be a minimum of 1 items in the array

Comment: It's not working

Comment: I used tweepy.API v1 I can post.  But V2 doesn't understand how to do that.

Comment: Interesting. I have absolutely no experience using tweepy so my ability to help you has come to an end. If you can, refer to Twitter's documentation. I'd recommend getting a cup of tea and setting aside some time because you can become lost in the documentation for hours.

Comment: For the next person that comes here I had a standalone app from the v1 days. I had to create a "Project" in the developer portal (https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/projects-and-apps) and then link that standalone app to the project for the above to work. After that the examples above worked fine.