# Tweepy [ Twitter API v2 ] unable to upload photo/media

Tags: python, api, file-upload, twitter, tweepy

```
import tweepy

ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'


api = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                       access_token=ACCESS_KEY, 
                       access_token_secret=ACCESS_SECRET,
                       consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
                       consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)


api.media_upload(file.jpg)
```

I'm unable to upload photos and get `media_ids`

**I don't have access to Twitter API V1**

Comment: Duplicate of [How to create tweet using tweepy API V 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70129448/how-to-create-tweet-using-tweepy-api-v-2) - please don't post the same thing again.

Answer (score 7):

`Client.media_upload` does not exist because Twitter API v2 does not have an endpoint for uploading media yet. This [is on the Twitter Developer Platform Roadmap](https://trello.com/c/Zr9zDrJx/109-replacement-of-media-uploads-functionality).

For now, you'll have to apply for Elevated access to use Twitter API v1.1 to upload media.